Script to upgrade Windows 10 to Windows 11
I want to create a script to unattended upgrade my Windows 10 machines to Windows 11, but I don't want to install in the process all unnecessary applications like xbox.
I'm trying to upgrade my Windows 10 machines to Windows 11 in a script, but I don't want to install the new Windows 11 applications I don't use.

cool story, bro. What do you want us to do about it?

I have a lot of computers, so I need to update all in an unattended way

So this is probably best accomplished with a two-step process:

Upgrade your workstations
Remove the things you don't want

Step 1 can be achieved in a lot of ways

A powershell script (https://christitus.com/install-windows-update-powershell/)
An MDT or SCCM Task sequence
An internal WSUS server and GPO to push the Win 11 update
Any other automation tool like Puppet, Chef, Ansible, etc.

Step 2 is similar. Most of the above tools have capabilities to remove feature sets like xbox. Or if you have the appropriate Microsoft licenses you could also try a non-standard windows install like Windows 11 N which removes those features.
Unfortunately ServerFault isn't going to write your script for you but you could search GitHub or Powershell Gallery to see if someone else has already posted one.

Upgrade Command: Use this command to start an unattended upgrade and skip dynamic updates:
setup.exe /auto upgrade /dynamicupdate disable
